# sort based on two fields in json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I want to sort the the json data based on two fields.I want to sort the data based on geo and username first I want to sort based on geo and sort the user within the geo .eg in geo 'Europe'
sort the user alphabetically and 'middle east' geo after

```js
const response = [{Username: "Denisse Morales", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2},
 {Username: "Chandra Jeevan J", Geo: "US East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 1},
 {Username: "Amy Khalil", Geo: "US West", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2},
 {Username: "Ashuwinth Panneer", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 1},
 {Username: "John Joshuva", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3},
 {Username: "Jose Alberto", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 2},
 {Username: "Dhivya Muthusamy", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 10},
 {Username: "Faizan Mohammed", Geo: "Middle East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3},
 {Username: "Jaison Clinton", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 9}];
 
 response.sort((a, b) => a.Geo.localeCompare(b.Geo));
 response.sort((a, b) =>  a.Username.localeCompare(b.Username));
 console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```js
const response = [ { Username: "Denisse Morales", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2, }, { Username: "Chandra Jeevan J", Geo: "US East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 1, }, { Username: "Amy Khalil", Geo: "US West", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2, }, { Username: "Ashuwinth Panneer", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 1, }, { Username: "John Joshuva", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3, }, { Username: "Jose Alberto", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 2, }, { Username: "Dhivya Muthusamy", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 10, }, { Username: "Faizan Mohammed", Geo: "Middle East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3, }, { Username: "Jaison Clinton", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 9, }, ];
response.sort(
  (a, b) => a.Geo.localeCompare(b.Geo) || a.Username.localeCompare(b.Username)
);
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the concatenated Geo and Username.

```js
const response = [{Username: "Denisse Morales", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2},
 {Username: "Chandra Jeevan J", Geo: "US East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 1},
 {Username: "Amy Khalil", Geo: "US West", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 2},
 {Username: "Ashuwinth Panneer", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 1},
 {Username: "John Joshuva", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3},
 {Username: "Jose Alberto", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 2},
 {Username: "Dhivya Muthusamy", Geo: "Europe", Status: "Reaches", month: "June", Week2: 10},
 {Username: "Faizan Mohammed", Geo: "Middle East", Status: "Reaches", month: "May", Week2: 3},
 {Username: "Jaison Clinton", Geo: "NSU", Status: "Reaches", month: "April", Week2: 9}];
 
 response.sort((a, b) => {
  return (a.Geo + a.Username) > (b.Geo + b.Username) ? 1 : -1;
 });
 console.log(response);
```

Comment: this does not respect same (read equal) values, beside the problem of the string lengths of each property.